# Processing a request that depends on two clicks in Sinatra

Tags: javascript, ruby, session, sinatra

I'm extending my checkers game engine (built in Ruby) to the web using Sinatra.

I need to get two clicks (to and from squares) to construct a complete move and send back a correct board state. I have already got it to render squares, each looks like:

```
<td id=<%= "A3" class= "open-square"><a href="/gameplay/A3></a></td>
```

if empty and

```
<td id=<%= "A3" class= "open-square"><a href="/gameplay/A3><img checker></a></td>
```

if occupied (I've stripped out the ERB cause its irrelevant here)

I have a route that looks like this:

```
get '/gameplay/:location' do
    erb :gameplay
end
```

It does a fine job of capturing individual clicks, but I need two. I got a great suggestion from [Tom Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69948/tom-andersen):

> Checkers is 64 squares, each square in one of three states, so -
>   without using cookies - you can use javascript on the browser to
>   create your state - 64 characters that are like 'br_bb___...' for
>   black, red and blank, then send that 64 char string along with the
>   clicked square. The server then sends back a new state, which the
>   local js uses to display the squares.

But I think this would only work if I could get a complete move from one click, which I can't. I'm new to this stuff, obviously naive, whatever advice you may have is appreciated.

Comment: I think the best way would be to "pre-process" those two clicks with javascript first and then do an AJAX call based on that. There is no clean way to associate two clicks on the server side if they come in as different requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't end up using JQuery to register the clicks. I basically created a querystring to register the locations of the clicks and used server-side programming to determine when to execute a move.